# How to remove elements of a vector with a predicate based on another vector

Tags: c++11, vector, stl, erase

I have two vectors

```
std::vector<Mat> images;
std::vector<std::string> image_paths;
```

and would like to filter out the indices in both vectors where the image is empty. This can easily be done on a single vector:

```
std::remove_if(images.begin() images.end(), [](const Mat& img) { return img.empty(); });
```

But now I'd like to remove the very same indices on image_paths as well. This can of course be generalized to vectors of arbitrary types or arbitrary predicates. How can I do this most elegantly?

Comment: You could have created a struct with two elements, `Mat` and `string` (and whatever other fields you need to keep together), and had a vector of those structs; rather than trying to keep two separate vectors in sync.

Comment: I've thought about that but for most further processing I need separate access to either vector and don't want to tightly couple both fields. It makes my life easier in this case but then I have to change all other interfaces to either take the coupled data vector or write code to extract the singular component vectors which also seems somewhat impractical and inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
std::erase(std::remove_if(image_paths.begin(), image_paths.end(),
  [&](const std::string& path) {
    auto index = &path - &image_paths.front();
    return images[index].empty();
  }), image_paths.end());

std::erase(std::remove_if(images.begin(), images.end(),
  [](const Mat& img) { return img.empty(); }), images.end());
```

Only works for `std::vector`, where flat storage is guaranteed.